# Ejecutar tareas Schedule Periodicamente LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, schedule

tengo un problema con mis tareas no se si pueden ayudarme.

Verán, estoy intentando crear una tarea programada con lo que Laravel ofrece, usando los Schedule. La tarea no es compleja.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
        $fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');

        $hora = date('H', time());

            if ($hora >= 0 && $hora <=12) {
                $turno = 'morning';
            }else{
                if($hora >= 13 && $hora <=24){
                    $turno =  'late';
                }
            }

        $FichasHoy = DB::table('fichamedica')
        ->where('fecha','=',$fecha_actual)
        ->where('turno','=',$turno)
        ->get();

        foreach ($FichasHoy as $Date ) {
            if($Date->estado == 0 || $Date->estado == 2){
                
                
                DB::table('pacientes')
                ->where('ID','=',$Date->Paciente_ID)
                ->update(['strikes' => DB::raw('strikes+1')]);
            }
        }
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

La tarea esta bien, el problema es que cuando ejecuto el comando `php artisan schedule:run` en mi consola, ejecuta la tarea una sola vez, y yo le puse que lo hiciera cada minuto.
No se si tengo que programar algo mas desde consola, o algun comando.

`* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Algo como esto, el problema es que aun no me dieron acceso a un servidor donde pueda probarlo, y tampoco se muy bien donde agregar ese comando.

Comment: Eso que ves `* * * * * cd /path-to-your...` es un comando para programar un **cron** que ejecutara `php artisan schedule:run` cada **1 minuto** y obviamente ese comando analiza si hay alguna tarea para ejecutar en ese minuto preciso que se ejecute y de ser así, la ejecuta

Comment: Puedo explicarte cómo ejecutar una tarea **cron** en, por ejemplo una distro **Linux** como **Ubuntu** pero sería algo extenso para un comentario y no tan relevante a esta pregunta

Comment: Segun laravel, solo debo agregar esta entrada Cron  `* * * * * cd /path-to-your...` a mi servidor. Osea, es solo agregar esto y ya? o hay que programar algo mas?

Comment: Solo debo añadir la entrada CRON a CPanel algo asi? [Añadir Cron Job](https://www.wnpower.com/blog/que-es-tarea-cron-jobs-cpanel/)

Comment: Exacto, supongamos que tienes tu proyecto en la ruta `/var/www/html/laravel` entonces tendrias que agregar la entrada **cron** con el comando `php /var/www/html/laravel artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1`, con un `*` asterisco en todos los campos de tiempo, desde *minuto* hasta *semana*. El `> /dev/nul ...` solo hará que su salida sea enviada "a la nada" por decirlo así, y todos los asteriscos que sea ejecutada cada minuto sin parar, lo cual es lo que se necesita

Comment: Genial, entonces solo queda montar todo esto al servidor y añadir la entrada Cron. y ya deberia de funcionar, verdad? Muchas gracias bro.

Comment: Claro desde **CPanel** es más sencillo, justo así como te explique, suerte :D